# How to emit an event with indexed fields in Huff

Tags: assembly, blockchain, solidity

When I want to emit an event that has 4 items

`#define event MyEvent(address indexed to, uint256 amountIn, uint256 block, uint256 amountOut)`

I understand that in this case I have two topics which is the event sig and the indexed address; These two are passed on the stack and the rest are abi encoded into the data?

If so, how would I structure the code. This is what I have so far but It's not emitting the right number of params. It leaving out `amountOut` and the values are not decoded right in the order

```
emitNoProfitEvent:
0x04 calldataload 0x180 mstore             // [store amountOut]
number 0x1a0 mstore                        // [store block]
0x04 calldataload 0x1c0 mstore             // [store amountIn]
0x04 calldataload                          // [indexedAddress]
__EVENT_HASH(NoProfitToTake)               // [sig, indexedAddress]
0x60 0x180                                 // DATA(amountIn, block, amountOut)
log2                                       // []
```